# Not able to run Eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse, windows-7

I am trying to run Eclipse Galileo, but having following error message on screen:

[image]

I have installed jdk-6u21-windows-x64 and also added the environment variables in the PATH. I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a 64-bit JDK, you should probably get the 64-bit Eclipse instead.  They really should match.